# Google Analytics: subdomains and Apache's basic auth

Tags: apache, google-analytics

I have two question to which I can't seem to find clear answers.

(1) I have GA tracking set-up for my **domain.com**.

(2) I also have the same tracking code set in the `<head>` of some other subdomains: **sub1.domain.com**, **sub2.domain.com**, etc.

(3) The subdomains are protected with Apache's basic auth which requires to provide a username and a password to access them.

**Questions:**

1. Does GA automatically tracks traffic from subdomains?
2. Is it possible that GA still sends calls from auth-protected
   subdomains?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. While you have to set a domain name in the configuration tracking is not limited to that domain; Google Analytics tracks traffic from every domain with the given account id, be it domains and subdomains or different domains (except that sessions are interrupted if the user switches between domains unless you have set up cross domain tracking).  So that is a yes, subdomains will be tracked.
2. Basic Auth prevents people from accessing your site, it does not prevent your site from accessing urls on the internet. The call to Googles tracking server is, at the end of the day, simply a call to some url. So yes, Google will still send calls from auth-protected (sub-)domains.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again!